# How to keep running a program during a time period?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timeout

I want to repeatedly run a program for a maximum of 5 seconds.

I know that `timeout` executes a command for the amount of time specified, e.g.:

```
timeout 5 ./a.out
```

But I want to keep executing the program until 5 seconds have passed so I can tell how
many times it was executed.

I figured that I need something like this:

```
timeout 5 `while true; do ./a.out; done`
```

but this is not working. I've already tried to create a shell script that calculates
the elapsed time of every loop iteration and subtracts it from the start time,
but that is inefficient.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `timeout 5 bash -c "while true; do ./a.out; done"`

Comment: If you want to use `timeout`, the command is `timeout 5s ./a.out`

Comment: Yeah, I found out that bash -c "" would do that! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use timeout:

```
timeout 5s ./a.out
```

You can write a short script and easily set an `end time` with `date -d "date string" +%s` to get a future time in seconds. Then just compare `current time` to `end time` and break on `true`. This allows you to capture additional data during your execution time period. For example, the following code sets the end time `5 seconds` in the future and then loops until `current time` equals `end`.

```
#!/bin/bash

end=$(date -d "+ 5 seconds" +%s)        # set end time with "+ 5 seconds"
declare -i count=0

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $end ]; do      # compare current time to end until true
    ((count++))
    printf "working... %s\n" "$count"   # do stuff
    sleep .5
done
```

**output:**

```
$ bash timeexec.sh
working... 1
working... 2
working... 3
working... 4
working... 5
working... 6
working... 7
working... 8
working... 9
```

In your case you would do something like

```
./a.out &                               # start your application in background
apid=$(pidof a.out)                     # save PID of a.out

while [ $(date +%s) -lt $end ]; do
    # do stuff, count, etc.
    sleep .5                            # something to prevent continual looping
done

kill $apid                              # kill process after time test true
```